# Threadpooling assistance

Tags: c#, threadpool

I have looked up about threadpooling and etc and found an example of it.  At the moment was i trying to recreate the example i saw for my own project and i keep getting this error when i input any number from the UI.

```
ManualResetEvent[] doneReadEvents = new ManualResetEvent[Read];
        ManualResetEvent[] doneWriteEvents = new ManualResetEvent[Write];
        ReadWrite[] ReadArray = new ReadWrite[Read];
        ReadWrite[] WriteArray = new ReadWrite[Write];

        for (int i = 0; i < Read; i++)
        {
            doneReadEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            ReadWrite Rw = new ReadWrite(Read, doneReadEvents[i]);
            ReadArray[i] = Rw;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Rw.ThreadPoolCallBackRead, i);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Write; i++)
        {
            doneReadEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            ReadWrite rW = new ReadWrite(Write, doneWriteEvents[i]);
            ReadArray[i] = rW;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(rW.ThreadPoolCallBackWrite, i);
        }

        WaitHandle.WaitAny(doneReadEvents);
        WaitHandle.WaitAny(doneWriteEvents);
        temp.Items.Add("Complete");
        temp.Items.Add("Closing");
        Output.DataSource = ReadWrite.MyList;
        Work.DataSource = ReadWrite.MyList2;
        ReadWrite.ReadData(Read);


    }
```

the first line in the first loop i get an error saying it is out of bound of the array.  when that error clears i dont know if there will be any more errors

```
namespace MultiThreadingReaderWriter
{
    class ReadWrite
    {
        public int _rw;

        public ManualResetEvent _doneEvents;

        public List<string> myList = new List<string>();
        public List<string> myList2 = new List<string>();
        public List<string> MyList{ get { return myList; } }
        public List<string> MyList2{ get { return myList2; } }
        public int RW { get { return _rw; } }


        //Constructor

        public ReadWrite(int rw, ManualResetEvent doneEvents)
        {
            _rw = rw;

            _doneEvents = doneEvents;

        }

        public void ThreadPoolCallBackRead(Object threadContext)
        { 
            int threadindex = (int) threadContext;
            myList.Add("Thread Read " + threadindex+ " started");
            ReadData(_rw);
            myList.Add("Thread Read " + threadindex + " done");
            _doneReadEvents.Set();

        }
        public void ThreadPoolCallBackWrite(Object threadContext)
        {
            int threadindex = (int)threadContext;
            myList.Add("Thread Write " + threadindex + " started");
            WriteData(_rw);
            myList.Add("Thread Write " + threadindex + " done");
            _doneWriteEvents.Set();
        }
        public void ReadData(int reader)
        {

            myList.Add("Reader " + reader + " has entered Critical Section");
            myList.Add("Reader " + reader + " is Reading");
            myList.Add("Reader " + reader + " is leaving Critical Section");

        }

        public void WriteData(int writer)
        {

            myList.Add("Writer " + writer + " has entered Critical Section");
            myList.Add("Writer " + writer + " is writing");
            myList.Add("Writer " + writer + " is leaving Critical Section");

        }
    }
}
```

this is the class connected to that above form program.

Answer (score 0):

Array indices start from zero and the right way to iterate would be

```
for (int i = 0; i < Read; i++)
{
}

for (int i = 0; i < Write; i++)
{ 
}
```

Comment: fixed that issue that you mentioned above, now i getting an error for this line of code `Output.DataSource = ReadWrite.MyList;`  saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: seems like you have not intialized datasource.you have to do something like datasource= new List().check ur code.

Comment: i have this `public List<string> myList = new List<string>();        public List<string> MyList{ get { return myList; } }` in the class though

Comment: what is output.datasource? is datasource a list<> object

Comment: output is the name of the listcontrol, DataSource is an object from ListControl.DataSource that gets or sets the data source for this system.windows.forms.listcontrol,  i just realized that part about output.datasource wasnt in the original post i just put it there now